# localdate cannot be converted date

Tags: javafx, datapicker

FXML on datepicker

@FXML
private DatePicker dp_detay_cal;

pojo.setFirstDate(dp_detay_cal.getValue());

error: localdate cannot be converted date

how to converted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred solution would be to use a `LocalDate` as the type for your `firstDate` property in your pojo class.

A `java.util.Date` includes more information that a `LocalDate`; it includes a time (of day) and a time zone. So you need to include some values for those before you can convert to a `Date`.

If, for some reason, you can't change the pojo class, try

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = dp_detay_cal.getValue().atStartOfDay();
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
Instant instant = Instant.from(zonedDateTime);
pojo.setFirstDate(Date.from(instant));
```

Comment: pojo.setFirstDate(new java.sql.Date(Date.from(instant).getTime()));

util.date to sql.date

run code :) ty